# Using transactionally in Slick 3

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

Usually you would run two or more statements in a transaction. But in all the examples I could find on using `transactionally` in Slick 3, there's a for comprehension to group these statements, when I usually use the `for` in a loop.

This works (deleting from two tables in a transaction):

```
   val action = db.run((for {
      _ <- table1.filter(_.id1 === id).delete
      _ <- table2.filter(_.id2=== id).delete
    } yield ()).transactionally)
    val result = Await.result(action, Duration.Inf)
```

But is the `for/yield` needed? is there an alternative way just to run two or more statements in a transaction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `transactionally` on every `DBIOAction`, not just those that are a result of the for comprehension. For example you can use `transactionally` in combination with the `DBIO.seq` method, which takes a sequence of actions and runs them sequentially:

```
val firstAction = table1.filter(_.id === id1).delete
val secondAction = table2.filter(_.id === id2).delete

val combinedAction = DBIO.seq(
  firstAction,
  secondAction
).transactionally
```

Answer (score 7):

For your case `for/yield` is not the only way to get what you need. But you will have to substitute it for the equivalent representation.
The for comprehension is [syntactic sugar](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) for a combination of `flatMap`s and a `map`. We need to use them because we are using monadic composition to aggregate all the actions in a `BDIOAction`.
So you could also write it as:

```
val action = db.run(
  table1.filter(_.id1 === id).delete.map ( _ =>
    table2.filter(_.id2=== id).delete
  ).transactionally
)
val result = Await.result(action, Duration.Inf)
```

The for comprehension is usually used because is more clean, easier to understand and very easy to scale.

Lets have a look at an example with 4 statements in a transactions to see how it looks:

- This would be with a for comprehension:

  ```
  val action = db.run((for {
    _ <- table1.filter(_.id1 === id).delete
    _ <- table2.filter(_.id2=== id).delete
    _ <- table3.filter(_.id3=== id).delete
    _ <- table4.filter(_.id4=== id).delete
  } yield ()).transactionally)
  val result = Await.result(action, Duration.Inf)
  ```
- This would be with `flatMap/map`s:

  ```
  val action = db.run(
    table1.filter(_.id1 === id).delete.flatMap ( _ =>
      table2.filter(_.id2 === id).delete.flatMap ( _ =>
        table3.filter(_.id3 === id).delete.map ( _ =>
          table4.filter(_.id4=== id).delete
        )
      )
    ).transactionally
  )
  val result = Await.result(action, Duration.Inf)
  ```

Comment: Your examples seem to be incorrect. Each of `map` calls should actually be `flatMap` calls, otherways that last action in map won't be executed, it would just create an action and discard it.